# How does D3 node selection work in D3 force graph?

Tags: force-layout, d3.js

I'm trying to create a force graph and inserting foreignObject for each node.

```
    simulation
            .nodes(graph.nodes)
            .on("tick", ticked)
            .on("end", graphended);

       var node   = svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "nodes")
                    .selectAll("circle")
                    .data(graph.nodes)
                    .enter().append("foreignObject")
                                 .attr("width",img_w)
                                 .attr("height",img_h)
                            .append("xhtml:body")
                            .html(function(d){ 
                                return '<span class="custom-icon-container-circle">Some sample content</span>';
                            })
                            .call(d3.drag()
                                    .on("start", dragstarted)
                                    .on("drag", dragged)
                                    .on("end", dragended));
```

and in TICK function I've following way to assign `x` and `y` coordinates.

```
function ticked() {
            node
                .attr("x", function(d) {
                    var xPos = findPosX(d.x, img_w);
                    return xPos-img_w/2;
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    var yPos = findPosY(d.y, img_h);
                    return yPos-img_h/2;
                });
        }
```

But in this tick method, instead of giving `x` and `y` Position to `foreignObject` it is assigning position to `body` element inside the foreignObject, which is making the node not position at actual coordinates.

Now, the code does work (if I remove foreignObject and place another element tag and the position is given to that element), so I think there is a problem in my selector and append statement that creates `foreignObject` above, as it is selecting inside body of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3` method chaining returns the last thing that returns something, in your case this is the `.append("xhtml:body")`, so `node` is holding a reference to that not to the `foreignObject`.  Change your code to:

```
var node = svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "nodes")
 .selectAll("circle")
 .data(graph.nodes)
 .enter().append("foreignObject")
 .attr("width",img_w)
 .attr("height",img_h);

node.append("xhtml:body")
  .html(function(d){ 
    return '<span class="custom-icon-container-circle">Some sample content</span>';
  })
  .call(d3.drag()
  .on("start", dragstarted)
  .on("drag", dragged)
  .on("end", dragended));
```